# ProcessBuilder keep process window from closing

Tags: java, process, command, processbuilder

I am using ProcessBuilder to execute a program. Currently when I execute the process the program opens up, runs its scripts and then immediately closes. I would like to keep the program open after I execute the process. Is such a thing possible?

Code is similar to this implementation in a separate thread

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("b32", "aess" );
pb.start();
```

Of course inputstream and errors streams are also output to console.

Comment: You'd have to create some kind of pause within the external process/script.

Comment: What is the program? CMD?

Comment: It is an in-house program at my work that monitors hardware. Unfortunately the software needs to be open to be communicating with the hardware to share the debug information.

Comment: Share the code you are using to execute the process

Comment: I made an edit to the question with the code